# Jenkins- Node,executor management

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

Currently, I have 2 nodes and which points to 2 different machines and both node has different labels to it and we have say 10 jobs . We are using freestyle jobs for all

```
 1. Node1 ->A Label -> A machine on this 9 job runs
 2. Node2 ->B Label -> B machine on this 1 job run
```

Each node has 5 executor assign to it. For `node1` its all executors are begin used as 9 jobs are running on it
For `node2` we have assigned 1 job and which run only sometimes so for `node2` rest 4 executors are unused.

it's their way I can assign other 4 executors for different jobs n dedicate 1 executor to a different job.
one way I can think to create one more node say

```
Node3 ->A Label -> B machine with 4 executors
```

and then for the rest of the job assign label so Jenkins will take care of it and for `node2` assign 1 executor with a different label
so it will look like

```
 1. Node1 ->A Label -> A machine -> 5 executors
 2. Node2 ->B Label -> B machine -> 1 executor
 3. Node3 ->A Label -> B machine  -> 4 executors
```

is this good practice to create 2 nodes that point to the same machine? any other good way where we can assign jobs to executor apart from labels. So basically I want 1 executor always free for 1 job and the rest job can work as per the executor's availability

Comment: Creating two nodes on the same machine is a big NO. We cannot assign jobs at the executor level. Now that we have those things behing us, I wonder if you can solve this problem just using the right labels across machines. Have one label just for B machine and put that label into that 1 job. For jobs which you want to run in A as well as B create a label "Node AB" and tag all 9 jobs to this label.

Comment: we can assign only 1 label to each node or m I missing something ?in my case node 1 and node3 will have same label node ab? if so then we assign 1 machine 2 nodes

Comment: Aha! We can assign more than 1 label to each node. Just leave a space and write another name and it will be considered as two labels! This should solve your problem.